# Jquery click function only works on one instance of a Button

Tags: jquery

I'm using the same button twice on one page,  but this click function is only working for one of them:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#back_button').click(function(){
        window.location.replace('__mem_url__');
    });
</script>
```

Here's the button:

```
<input type="submit" id="back_button" value="Back to Memberships" name="adm_mlevels_update" class="form_input_submit">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The id of a DOM element should be **unique**. You are using an id selector `$('#back_button')` so this will apply to only a single button as there could be only a single element in your document with `id="back_button"`. You could use a class selector instead:

```
$('.form_input_submit').click(function(){
    window.location.replace('__mem_url__');
});
```